# C serial port not receiving data properly

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, embedded

I have an extremely frustrating problem, and any constructive feedback would be most useful!!

I am sending data to my C application(made in Microsoft Visual Studio) from a microprocessor(MSP430). But trying to receive large amounts of data, say 200 kbytes doesn't seem possible.

I thought at first it was my hardware but I tried recieving the data in realterm and it was fine. I don't know if its an issue with speed or what. But its extremely annoying!!

If anyone knows a way to receive large amounts of data in C that would be brilliant.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Hard to answer something usefull with no more information. Please give more details/code of your application...

Comment: You receive large amounts of data by receiving little amounts at a time, repeatedly.

Comment: I am just looking for an explanation to the fact that with the same code I am able to receive data properly with Realterm app but not with a C app made in visual studio using winsock. Yes I am receiving large amount of data, actually I am receiving live data continuously one byte at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your serial library on windows side.

After opening the port, inside read function... you might need to add loop to wait until bytes are received.

But as other suggested, you have given no useful info to conclude.